# MS Access: Count selected items in multi-valued field on a form

Tags: count, multivalue, ms-access-forms

I have a Microsoft Access form with a multi-valued field. I'd like to display the number of items a user has selected to the right of that field. The field is called [Description]. The control displaying in red is =Count([Description]). It counts how many options there are in the [Description] field as opposed to how many have been selected. Any thoughts on how I can just count selected items?

[image]

Comment: I can't explain why but when reviewing the database today, the formula is working how I want it to. In the example above, the red number now says 2. I didn't change the formula so I'm not sure what happened there. So, consider this issue closed.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that if my form is filtered for a single record, the formula works - it shows the number of items that are flagged in the Description field for that record.

If my form is not filtered (even though its 'Default View' property is set to 'Single Form'), it shows the total number of possible options in the Description field.

Very strange behaviour indeed.